# Attempted import error: 'createstore' is not exported from 'redux'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

am getting an error while i created small redux application error are like createstore is not exported don't know where i am wrong please help or tell me where i learn redux for best practices.

```
import {createstore} from 'redux';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const initialState = {
    todos : [
        {
          "userId": 1,
          "id": 1,
          "title": "delectus aut autem",
          "completed": false
        },
        {
          "userId": 1,
          "id": 2,
          "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
          "completed": false
        },
        {
          "userId": 1,
          "id": 3,
          "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
          "completed": false
        }
   
      ]
}


const todoReducer = (state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const store = createstore(todoReducer);
export default store;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `createStore` not `createstore`. You have a typo in your code.

`import {createStore} from "redux"`